# Conditional formatting on a spilled range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(* This might be a duplicated question, but it would be surprising if we don't have this feature yet. *)

I have a table `Table5` in Column C, whose height may change. in Column E, I have a formula to e.g., extract unique values, thus the resulting spilled range has a dynamic height.

I would like to make a conditional formatting over the resulting spilled range, for instance, highlight the value which is greater than 5.

But I didn't find how to define a conditional formatting rule over a spilled range (e.g., by using `#`). I don't want to apply the conditional formatting rule over the whole column.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You can put something like `=E4#` in the "Applies To" range, but it'll change to the hard-coded equivalent, e.g. `$E$4:$E$7`. Not sure this is a feature yet.

Comment: Indeed, `=E4#` became `E4:E7` which is fixed.

Comment: In short, you can't.  Just like you cannot refer to a structured reference, one must use an actual range in the applies to.  Since structured references have been around for a long time and not added, I do not see them adding this ability.

Comment: There is indeed a workaround for structured references. I tried it, it worked so far: https://superuser.com/a/1517828/86126

Comment: @SoftTimur that works for the formula, but not the `applies to:`.  The `Applies to:` will change it to an actual range no matter how it is entered.  And that range will remain fixed regardless if the table increases or decreases in size.

Comment: I did a quick test with a table and structured reference. I selected the table, and made rules with `=INDIRECT("Table1[@col1]")...`, it seemed to work dynamically regardless of the change of table size.

Comment: hmm, I stand corrected on the structured ref.  The applies to acts like an insert on the add.  But it still does not work on the spilled range as that is not seen as an insert but just changing the values on existing cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate workaround is to use a named range which **will** accept the spill range `#` assignation.

> Assign Named Range "CF_1" as:

```
=OFFSET($E$4,0,0,COUNTA($E$4#))
```

> The conditional formatting to be applied to E:E can then be:

```
=AND(ROW(E1)=MEDIAN(ROW(E1),MIN(ROW(CF_1)),MAX(ROW(CF_1))),E1>5)
```

In essence, this isn't too much different to the answers by JvdV and Professor Pantsless as it kind of boils down to the same thing, but it does have the bonus that it will only apply to only the rows of the spill range (the cells E1-E3 haven't been taken into account yet for the other answers to date).

***UPDATE***

And in fact, you don't have to use a named range at all as this code will also accept `#` (still can't work out how to apply over only the spill range though)

```
=AND(ROW(E1)=MEDIAN(ROW(E1),MIN(ROW(E$4#)),MAX(ROW(E$4#))),E1>5)
```

Comment: Are you sure `=AND(ROW(E1)=MEDIAN(ROW(E1),MIN(ROW(E$4#)),MAX(ROW(E$4#))),E1>5)` works? I did not manage to reproduce that.

Comment: The approach of borrowing a name accepting spilled range works.

Comment: Yes, the non name approach works (or at least for me). However, if you update the `Applies to` range to E:E after putting the formula in, Excel may alter the formula automatically so just check that it is what you actually expect...

Answer (score 4):

The only way I could think of was:

```
=AND(ROW($E1)>=4,ROW($E1)<=COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Table5[Coefficient]")))+4,$E1>5)
```

Use the above formula as a conditional formatting rule on the whole of column E:E.

Comment: I use `UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Table5[Coefficient]"))` as an example, the real formula is more complex than that. I would prefer to use directly `E4#` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a conditional formatting rule over the whole column, but use some additional logic to ensure it only applies to the range you want, ie:

```
=AND(ROW(E1)>=4, ROW(E1)<=4+COUNT(UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Table5[Coefficient]"))), [your condition here])
```

Apply the rule to `E:E` and it will only evaluate to `True` for rows in the range you want.

**Update**

The `Indirect` reference can use the spill range, so you could use:

```
=AND(ROW(E1)>=4, ROW(E1)<=4+COUNT(INDIRECT("E4#")), [your condition here])
```

Note that `Unique` is no longer needed. Also, this assumes the values in your table are only numbers.

Comment: That's seriously scary. The minute I edited my question you posted the exact same!

Comment: This seemed to be where the trail was leading from the comments. Also the best workaround I could think of to "not" apply it to the whole column.

Comment: I use `UNIQUE(INDIRECT("Table5[Coefficient]"))` as an example, the real formula is more complex than that. I would prefer to use directly `E4#` somewhere.

Comment: Added an improvement which uses `E4#`. The rule still applies to the whole column, but should evaluate to `FALSE` outside of the spilled range and not apply the formatting there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using several different conditional formats applied to the entire column, or group of columns. The table looks like this:

[image: Example table]

The following formulas are conditional formatting applied to the entire row/rows, not individual cells:

Header:

```
=AND(OR(ISERR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)),ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)))=TRUE,ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE)
```

Band:

```
=AND(CELL("row",A1)=EVEN(CELL("row",A1)),ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE)
```

Last row (or total row):

```
=AND(ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE,ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE)
```

With the following formatting:

[image: Formatting]

---

If you do not want this formatting to be applied to non-spill cells, you can determine if a cell was spilled or directly input. You can do this with a formula or write a UDF.

Using a formula you need to fake it. You can use `ISFORMULA` to find where the spill formula was entered, and `NOT(ISBLANK())` to identify spilled rows. You would then have to assume a formula followed by non-blank, non-formula cells is a spilled formula. Helper columns may be helpful.

Using a UDF, you can directly determine if a cell is spilled. Below is a basic example. You can add more checking to determine if the formula is actually spilled if desired.

```
Public Function isFormulaOrSpill(ByVal rRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim this_bIsSpill As Boolean
    Dim this_bIsFormula As Boolean
    
    this_bIsSpill = rRange.HasSpill
    this_bIsFormula = rRange.HasFormula
    
    isFormulaOrSpill = (this_bIsSpill Or this_bIsFormula)
End Function
```

---

Recently I've been building entire tables as spilled ranges (including header and total rows). Here is an example of those who want to give it a shot:

```
=LET(
    Column_Key, Table_Status[System],
    Column_FtEstimated, Table_Status[Estimated],
    Column_FtModeled, IF(Table_Status[Modeled]>Table_Status[Estimated],Table_Status[Estimated],Table_Status[Modeled]),

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(Column_Key)),
    Array_BoolKey, (TRANSPOSE(Column_Key)=Categories)+0,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Column_Filter1,List_Filter1))),
    Mask2, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Column_Filter2,List_Filter2))),

    Array_BoolMasked, Array_BoolKey,
    Masked_FtModeled, IFERROR(Array_BoolMasked*TRANSPOSE(Column_FtModeled),0),
    Masked_FtEstimated, IFERROR(Array_BoolMasked*TRANSPOSE(Column_FtEstimated),0),
    Array_Ones, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array_BoolMasked),1,1,0),

    Body_Count_Lines, MMULT(Array_BoolKey, Array_Ones),
    Body_Sum_FtModeled, MMULT(Masked_FtModeled, Array_Ones),
    Body_Sum_FtEstimated, MMULT(Masked_FtEstimated, Array_Ones),
    Body_Percent_FtModeled, IFERROR(Body_Sum_FtModeled/Body_Sum_FtEstimated,"-"),

    Total_Count_Lines, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Count_Lines),"-"),
    Total_Sum_FtModeled, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Sum_FtModeled),"-"),
    Total_Sum_FtEstimated, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Sum_FtEstimated),"-"),
    Total_Percent_FtModeled, IFERROR(Total_Sum_FtModeled/Total_Sum_FtEstimated,"-"),

    Array_Seq, {1,2,3,4,5},
    Array_Header, CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  "System", "Lines",  "Modeled Feet", "Estimated Feet", "Percent Modeled"),
    Array_Body, CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  Categories,  Body_Count_Lines,  Body_Sum_FtModeled, Body_Sum_FtEstimated,  Body_Percent_FtModeled),
    Array_Total, CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  "Total",        Total_Count_Lines,  Total_Sum_FtModeled, Total_Sum_FtEstimated,  Total_Percent_FtModeled),

    Range1,Array_Header,
    Range2,Array_Body,
    Range3,Array_Total,
    Rows1,ROWS(Range1), Rows2,ROWS(Range2), Rows3,ROWS(Range3), Cols1,COLUMNS(Range1),
    RowIndex, SEQUENCE(Rows1 + Rows2 + Rows3), ColIndex,SEQUENCE(1, Cols1),
    RangeTable,IF(
        RowIndex<=Rows1,
        INDEX(Range1,RowIndex,ColIndex),
        IF(RowIndex<=Rows1+Rows2,
            INDEX(Range2,RowIndex-Rows1,ColIndex),
            INDEX(Range3,RowIndex-Rows1-Rows2,ColIndex)
    )),

    Return, RangeTable,
    Return
)
```