# Check for/Detect Dynamic Array Spill in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, dynamic-arrays

I want to check for/detect cells that contain values spilled from a dynamic array.

Let's say I have data in the cells `A1:A10` and I write the formula `=A1:A10` in the cell `B1`, then `B1` itself will contain the actual formula and the values in `B2:B10` will be spilled from the dynamic array.

I want to be able to distinguish between the actual formula and the spilled values of the array. More explicitly: I want to write a conditional formatting rule that highlights spilled values (and only spilled values) of dynamic arrays on the sheet.

I would also be happy with a VBA public function that I can use in the conditional formatting, in the sense of something like `=IsSpilledValue(B:B)` returning TRUE or FALSE.

This question is not a duplicate of "[Conditional formatting on a spilled range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724096/conditional-formatting-on-a-spilled-range)" in my understanding.

> Edit 1:

The reason that I want to highlight only the spilled cells is so that users that are somewhat unfamiliar with dynamic arrays do not try to make changes in the spilled cells but only in the cell that contains the actual formula. However, I have to allow for complete manual override of other users, so locking cells is not an option. Highlighting would really work the best here.

Comment: Look into the [`Range.HasSpill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasspill) function in vba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the function you are looking for:

```vb
Public Function isSpilledValue(c As Range) As Boolean
isSpilledValue = c.HasSpill 
End Function
```

[image]

```vb
Public Function isSpilledValueAndNotSpillParent(c as range) as boolean
isSpilledValueAndNotSpillParent= c.HasSpill And c.Address <> c.SpillParent.Address
End Function
```

`SpillParent` returns the cell containing the formula.

[image]

Comment: This almost looks like what I am trying to achieve, but can this be amended to exclude the first cell, here `B1`, so that only the spilled values are highlighted?

Comment: hmm - that doesn't make sense - B1 is also a spilled value ... but I updated the function

Comment: Ah ok, that was a terminology misunderstanding on my part then.

Comment: Ok - according to your edit in the question I understand your requirement. But maybe it then makes more sense to have two conditions: one e.g. that makes the SpillParent green (= hi user, you can change the formula here) and a second using `isSpilledValueAndNotSpillParent` e.g. with color grey (= hi user, don't touch this)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. That was very helpfull. I think I can implement the parent-only formatting myself based on the code you've already provided here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will also work for you:
`=AND(NOT(ISFORMULA(B1)),NOT(ISBLANK(B1)))`

[image: pic]

However, this will highlight values entered in those cells as well but at least does not require VBA.

Comment: This suggestion would work for the micro example that I gave in the question, but not when applied to an actual data sheet with multiple tables and all sorts of calculations on it. Thanks for taking the time though.