# How to determine the number of cells needed for a dynamic array formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to determine how many rows are needed to hold the result of a dynamic array formula. Here's what I tried:

- Counting the rows of the range returned by CurrentArray: Generates Error 1004 No cells were found.
- Using Evaluate on the formula and checking LBound and UBound: Generates Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

**Example:**

Cell A1 has formula "=SEQUENCE(10)"

Using this code;

```
Sub check4array()
    Debug.Print Range("A1").HasArray
    Debug.Print Range("A1").CurrentArray.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print UBound(Evaluate(Range("A1").arrayformula))
End Sub
```

I get this output:

False

> Error 1004

There is something about arrays I'm not getting. Please help me understand!

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Hi @PeterT! It works, as long as I have no other content below the array.

Comment: Worth reading [check for/detect dynamic array spill in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882529/check-for-detect-dynamic-array-spill-in-excel), too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`.HasSpill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.hasspill) and `.SpillingToRange`:

```
Sub check4array()
    If Range("A1").HasSpill Then
         Debug.Print Range("A1").SpillingToRange.Rows.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

Dynamic array formulas are [different](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4) from the older array formulas.

Alternately, you can use the [spilled-range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd):

```
Debug.Print Range("A1#").Rows.Count
```

---

If A1 contains a `#SPILL!` error (i.e. something is blocking it from spilling), then `Evaluate` its `.Formula2` and then use `UBound`:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print UBound(.Evaluate(.Range("A1").Formula2), 1)
End With
```